# как оправить уведомление о нажатии кнопок владельцу бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Я хочу,чтобы при нажатии кнопки уходило дополнительное сообщение владельцу бота или в сам бот

```
import datetime
import config
import zakaz
import telebot
from telebot import types, TeleBot
from telebot.types import InlineKeyboardButton

bot: TeleBot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
#Создание кнопок
def get_text_messages(message):
    keyboard = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    button1 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Принять", callback_data="pr_zk")
    button2: InlineKeyboardButton = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Отклонить", callback_data="okl_zk")
    keyboard.row(button1, button2)
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, zakaz.opisanie,  reply_markup=keyboard)
#Ответ на принять заказ
    @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data =="pr_zk")
    def callback_function1(callback_obj):
        keyboard = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        button1 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Водитель", callback_data="vd")
        button2 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Водитель с грузчиками", callback_data="vd_gr")
        keyboard.row(button1, button2)
        bot.send_message(callback_obj.from_user.id, "Выберете", reply_markup=keyboard)
```

..........

```
        bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=callback_obj.id)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == "okl_zk")
def callback_function8(callback_obj):
    bot.send_message(callback_obj.from_user.id, "Позвоните мне по номеру:")
    bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=callback_obj.id)
bot.polling()
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте переслать сообщение при нажатии кнопки.

Можно так-же через request:

```
r=requests.get(https://api.telegram.org/bot" 
    + $token + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + $chat_id + "&text=" + $text)
```

Добавте это след. строкой после нужной 'кнопки'.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Я пробовал послать такое сообщение в качестве ответа на нажатие кнопки, но не понимаю, как и куда свой id  вставить, получаб ошибку чат такой-то не найден

Comment: chat_ib = ' ваш чат айди'

Comment: https://api.telegram.org/bot[ТОКЕН_БОТА]/sendMessage?chat_id=[ВАШ CHAT ID]&text=[ТЕКСТ СООБЩЕНИЯ]   токен можно добавить другого бота чтобы лог приходил в него

Comment: bot.send_message(message.chat_id = " мой id", " текст") Так?

Comment: у вас получилось?

Comment: Только завтра будет возможность проверить

Comment: нет,конструкция,что выше,не работает,пишет TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: chat not found"

Answer (score 0):

If <нажата кнопка>:
bot.send_message("your id", "Сообщение которое отослать")

Свой id можно получить print(message.from_user.id)
в каком либо блоке